# JPA + Hibernate, Error : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name value is not valid

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use JPA + Hibernate to call a Store procedure with @Query annnotation

```
@Query(value = "exec dbo.getUserById :Id", nativeQuery = true)
User findUserById(@Param("Id) Long id);
```

and map the result to the follow  entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_contact")
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    private String userName;
    private String value;
}
```

Store procedure only return 'id' and 'userName' columns, so when i call findUserById method Spring throws the follow  error

```
Error : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name 'value' is not valid
```

I guess its because Hibernate try to find 'value' property and map to 'value' property in the entity but for this query i dont need value property.

Its a requirement in the proyect that i only use store procedures to access to the database, so i can't use SQL native queries.

Is there any configuration available to specified ignore this property only for the call to this store procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
private String name;
```

Try changing "name" to say - "somename". This is causing the issue if you look at the exception. "name" is a reserved keyword. For simplicity if your entity is say `TheUser`, then use something like - `username` instead of `name`. I hope you got the idea !